# Remove all the Quotes from JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, solr

```
JSONArray error = data.getJSONArray("error");

                for (int it=0; it<error.length(); it++){
             error.toString().replaceAll("\"", " ");
                    System.out.println(error);
                }
```

I got a JSON response from a SOLR link which has been parsed into a JSONArray. Here in the code am trying to remove the double quotes from the JSONArray. But its not happening. Can anyone help me  at the earliest? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your JSON. What do you think `toString().replaceAll(...)` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: 'It's not happening' is not very specific, what's wrong?

Also you're looping through the array and never even referencing the index

Comment: Can you please modify your question to explain the expected output, given a specific input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see whats wrong. You are not printing the result from `replaceAll` call. To remove all quotes from json array output, try this.

```
JSONArray error = data.getJSONArray("error");
System.out.println(error.toString().replaceAll("\"", " "));
```

Please note, this will also remove any quotes inside array values, which might not be what you want. For example, the output of `["cool says \"meow\"","stuff"]` would be `[ cool says \ meow\  , stuff ]`. If you only want the string values, I recommend looking at the [org.json.JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) docs for `JSONArray::get(int)` and `JSONArray::length()`

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please let me know how to remove a back slash and double quotes from the array? i want to remove this \" these two characters with all the spaces leading and trailing. Am giving a double slash in the above code but its not working. Its showing compiler error.

Comment: Call `replaceAll` with four backslash characters. `replaceAll("\\\\", " ")`. Are you sure this is what you want? I've never shipped code to modify a json string like this because I usually want to retain the value that is stored in the array item. If the json object is `["cool says \"meow\""]`, shouldn't the expected value be `cool says "meow"` ?

Comment: yeah true in that case i should replace \" this with just the double quotes right?

Comment: Not only that, but you would have to also replace all unicode characters as outlined in the json spec https://www.json.org/. That is much more complicated to pull off and requires a lot of code. Please see my other solution assuming you want to print the values in their original form.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to print an array of json strings. If you replace all quotes it will also replace the quotes inside of strings and distort the value that was encoded. If someone did that to me, I wouldn't be very happy :). For instance look at this json.

```
[
  "hello",
  "cat says \"meow\"",
  "dog says \"bark\"",
  "the temperature is 15\u00B0"
]
```

Not only would the quotes be missing, but also the special unicode character for degrees would probably not look correct (`15°`). To return the value in it's original form, you would need to implement the entire [json spec](http://www.json.org/)! Thats a lot of work, probably not something you want to do. I've done it before and it wasn't easy.

Fortunately though, we are already using a library that does all of this for us :) Just use `org.json` package. It has everything you need to properly encode and decode values. You didn't think you would have to do all of that parsing yourself did you? To print the strings in their original form, you could do this.

```
/** use these imports
 *
 * import org.json.JSONArray;
 * import org.json.JSONObject;
 * import org.json.JSONException;
 **/
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

// add some strings to array
ja.put("hello");
ja.put("cat says \"meow\"");
ja.put("the temperature is 15\u00B0");

// add an int
ja.put(1);

// add an object
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("cool", "cool");
ja.put(jo);

// loop and print only strings
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); ++i) {
    try {
        // ignore null values
        if (!ja.isNull(i)) {
            System.out.println(ja.getString(i));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // not a string
        // try ja.getBoolean
        // try ja.getDouble
        // try ja.getInt
        // try ja.getJSONArray
        // try ja.getJSONObject
        // try ja.getLong
    }
}
```

To use with your original code, just replace `ja` with your own variable. Notice in the catch clause I put some comments show other methods you could use to read values in a parsed json object.

Comment: Can someone please help me with editing this question? I have been blocked to post new questions and I have some doubts which needs clarity from experts

Comment: @user3222718, I have only a few suggestions *grins mischievously*. Solving a problem always starts with identifying what caused it. Your description and title of the problem is too broad. Give examples of expected output.

*Search, and Research* - Needs work. There is a list of criteria defining how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow's /help section.

*Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague*: Could actually use some more words.

*Spelling, grammar and punctuation*: Needs work.

*Introduce Problem Before Code*: Needs work.